# REST API to reset password in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins

I have been exploring on the creation and update of the jenkins user's via REST API.

I find that there is a rest api that we can use to create the Jenkins user (securityRealm/createAccountByAdmin). However when there is a change to the user, there is no update REST api to invoke.

I am trying out the same with Java, If any suggestion, please share with me

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `/scriptText` endpoint and use groovy to update the user.

You will have to understand what is possible to do by reading the Jenkins javadoc
https://javadoc.jenkins.io/hudson/model/class-use/User.html

You can execute code and test it easily from the page `/script`